# Is there a way to use nVelocity view engine with MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-monorail, nvelocity

We currently have a site that was started over 6 years ago using Castle MonoRail V2 and the nVelocity View Engine.  The problem is that we would like to update our technology but are stuck due to this limitation.  I was thinking that since we can use different view engines within the same MVC project, is there a way to use nVelocity with MVC 4?

Seems the project is dead.

Comment: Have you seen http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/MvcContrib.ViewEngines.NVelocity/NVelocityViewEngine.cs ? This doesn't mean you can use your existing NVelocity views without modifications.

Comment: Ok...I've looked there but I think I'm missing something.  I can see in the source that there is a MvcContrib.ViewEngines namespace, but if I download the Release or the Extras.Release, I don't see this in the Object Browser.  

Do I need to grab the source and build it myself??

Comment: Haven't used it in years. If it's not in the binaries anymore, get the code and compile it, it's very easy...